# pulling lines related to the date

Tags: shell-script

I've got a text-file that's `sort`ed by the first field, which is month/day (eg: 02-20)

I've been using `grep` on rhe text file, but that's easiest to do with today's date, using the `date` command in a script.

I'd like to pull up the prior 3 days, today's date, and the coming 5 days... but I don't know an easy way to handle the end of the month/into the next month.  I could, I s'pose, hard code that in?  But I was looking for an elegant solution to the problem, so I'm seeking suggestions.

I'd prefer to use regular commands so the script is as portable as possible.

ie: by portable, I mean not just limited to Linux/GNU machines (and/or having to install specific utilities in order to make everything run).  Currently I think I'm on a BSD machine, and I've been on most flavors of UNIX (Solaris, blah, blah, blah) - and probably will be in the future.

I'd take something that's more convoluted to program/script, that uses very basic tools, over having to remember to install packages everytime I might be on a different flavor of UNIX (when I could just scp in my scripts directory and have it work).

---

FYI: Current `date` -d flag sets daylight savings time :)

```
 -d dst  Set the system's value for Daylight Saving Time.
```

---

Okay, I just gave an example (as asked) of the type on data in the file (it's much bigger, obvs), but I didn't give edge cases.  Here's an edge case, ie: how do I handle the end of month period, without programming in a test for the end of the month, for each month (Or 4 types of month: 30, 31, 28 & 29).

```
01-01   Something To Do Here    Notes that may run for a really long time
02-05   On the 5th of the Month         Do this other thing, because of X
02-06   The day after           Do this cleanup stuff
03-15   The Ides                Remember, remember the Brutus of December
03-29   Edge                    Does this show up on the 1st of April?
03-30   Edge2                   Does this show up on the 1st and 2nd?
03-31   Last day in the month   Shows?
04-01   Edge                    Does this show on 31st?  Or does it only show 03-35?
```

Comment: Define portable. It is trivial to do this for any Linux system since GNU `date` has some nifty tricks but that won't work on non-Linux systems. It will, however, work on _any_ GNU system, is that portable enough? Also, please [edit] your question and give us an example of your file so we know what we're dealing with.

Answer (score 3):

GNU date allows you to give strings to the `-d` option like `-2 days` and `5 days`. The `-f` option allows these strings to be read from a file or pipe. So using GNU `date` and `bash`:

```
printf '%d days\n' {-2..5} | date -f - +%m-%d | grep -f - in_file
```

#### Update

If `tcl` is acceptable, here is a script to print out the dates:

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set now [clock seconds]

for {set n -2} {$n<=5} {incr n} {
  set out_date [clock add $now $n days]
  puts [clock format $out_date -format %m-%d]
}
```

Just pipe the output of this to `grep -f -` as above.

Comment: `date` on the current machine I'm working with is POSIX.1, and has no -f option [-adjrtz]

Comment: @anon3202, if your `date` supports `-d` (note neither `-d` or `-f` are supported by POSIX), you might get away with using a loop - `for n in {-2..5}; do date -d "$n days" +%m-%d; done | grep -f - in_file`. Try it without the `grep` first to see if the dates get printed.

Comment: FYI: current `date` says "compliant with the IEEE Std 1003.1-2008"  Also, everything but today's date says: "date: settimeofday: Operation not permitted"

Comment: @anon3202, your `date` is POSIX compliant, but POSIX only requires that it have the `-u` option. Anything else is an extra. See the standard here - http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/date.html. I should have said 'required' above, but instead I put 'supported'.

Comment: @anon3202, the problem you have is that the POSIX standard doesn't provide a way to do date/time arithmetic in the shell. This means that you need to either use something else that does eg perl/python/tcl or write your own date increment/decrement functions (using `awk` would probably be best). Rolling your own a bit much for an SE answer, but its not that hard to do.

Answer (score 1):

Well here is a one liner that seems to do the job...

```
dt=$(date +%m-%d);for i in {-2..5}; do grep "$(echo "$dt"|awk -F"-" -v count=$i '{print $1"-0"$2+count}')" mtest; done
```

You can make this a function by adding this to your .bashrc ...

```
todolist(){  dt=$(date +%m-%d);for i in {-2..5}; do grep "$(echo "$dt"|awk -F"-" -v count=$i '{print $1"-0"$2+count}')" $1; done; }
```

and then you just call it

```
todolist whateverthefilename.txt
```

It isn't very pretty but I tested it with your data it did work.

```
$ echo -e "01-01   Something To Do Here    Notes that may run for a really long time\n02-05   On the 5th of the Month         Do this other thing,\nbecause of X\n02-06   The day after           Do this cleanup stuff\n03-15   The Ides                Remember, remember the Brutus of December">> mtest

$ dt=02-05; for i in {-2..5}; do grep "$(echo "$dt"|awk -F"-" -v count=$i '{print $1"-0"$2+count}')" mtest; done
02-05   On the 5th of the Month         Do this other thing,
02-06   The day after           Do this cleanup stuff
```

Comment: Why hardcode a zero into the day? You will get the correct date strings only 2 days a month!

Comment: @Graeme I missed that first time around. I was working only with your data. The zero is there because awk returns 5 when 04+1 is evaluated. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`touch` to POSIXLY test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html) the validity of a date string.

I'll use a couple options here.

- `-c`

  - Do not create a specified *file* if it does not exist. Do not write any diagnostic messages concerning this condition.
- `-t`

  - Use the specified time instead of the current time. The option-argument shall be a decimal number of the form:

    ```
    [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]
    ```
  - If the time cannot be represented as the file's timestamp, `touch` shall exit immediately with an error status.
  - Note that the `[[CC]YY]` fields are optional.

And so, for example:

```
testtime()
        if      command -v touch >&2
        then    touch -c ''
                eval '  touch -ct"$1" ""
                        [ "$?" = '"$? ]"
        else    { touch; } 2>&3
        fi      3>&2 2>/dev/null
```

It's pretty careful to handle matters portably, I think. In tests with both a GNU and an heirloom *(Solaris)* `touch`, the GNU tool returns 1 for a bad date and 0 for a good one, but the heirloom version returns 2 and 1 respectively. I'm fairly sure that the old Solaris tool's behavior is specifically referenced in the spec's rationale where I find:

- At least one historical implementation of `touch` incremented the exit code if `-c` was specified and the file did not exist. This volume of POSIX.1-2008 requires exit status zero if no errors occur.

I am more convinced when I compare the behavior of different versions of my heirloom tools. The one from the base set - which is designed to behave as much like the original set as is possible and still be useful on modern systems - is the one that returns the 2 and 1 as mentioned. However, when I use the `/usr/heirloom/bin/posix2001/touch` executable - which is the version which has been modified for standards compliance as necessary - it returns exactly as does the GNU tool.

In any case, the function handles both the old Solaris, the modified-for-compliance Solaris, and the GNU behaviors, because it compares the results of an intial call to `touch` on a `''`null file operand *(which definitely does not exist)* against a second call on same and returns 0 for a good date or 1 for a bad one. It returns 127 and writes to stderr if `touch` cannot be found.

Here's how you can use it:

```
testtime MMDD0000 && echo good date || echo bad date
```

...where *MM* and *DD* are 2-digit decimal strings representing the date you wish to test. You can also check for valid times that way - and even with a *`.S`* seconds field.

Answer (score 0):

I posted my first answer yesterday with way too little sleep. I am back and ready to try again. Rather than try to awk the dates I decided I was being too clever so I went back and rethought it.

```
todolist(){ for i in {-2..5}; do grep "$(date -d "${date} +$i days" +%m-%d)" $1 ; done; };
```

Just add the one-liner to your .bashrc and then feed it  the file.

This time I let date do all the work. I got the [hint from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18180581/subtract-days-from-a-date-in-bash).  This little bit will add any number of days from today's date and output it in the format you need for your file...

```
date -d "${date} +$i days" +%m-%d)"
```

The function above should now work without resorting to hard-coded values.

Comment: Except, I'm not adding anything to a file, I'm trying to specify what I'm extracting from a file.  File exists, but I only want a subset (what should've been done, and what needs to get done soon) out of it.  Not things that need to be done 6 months from now.

Comment: This isn't much different in essence from the first answer I gave. The issue is that the `+n days` syntax with `date` is not portable. AFAIK it is specific to GNU `date`. POSIX doesn't even require that `date` has a `-d` option - see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html

Comment: @anon3202 This method (and the one initially given by Graeme) will pull out only the things due on "today's date, 2 days previous to and 5 days later. It is not pulling things 6 months from the date.  Of course Graeme's point about whether this will work for you is still valid.

Comment: @anon3202 Try this to test your date command---

for i in {-2..5}; do echo "$(date -d "${date} +$i days" +%m-%d)" $1 ; done ---

you should get a list of 8 days

Comment: results: 3 of today's date (duplicates), and 5 'settimeofday: operation not permitted'.  rcjohnson: I was replying to: "output it in the format you need for your file" - which I *don't* need.  Not adding anything to the file.

Comment: @anon3202 It appears that your date command is not compatible with the  date -d switch.  Unfortunately I only have GNU Linux boxes so I am not able to provide any better advice on your particular situation.

Also I did not mean that the file would be changed, I only meant that the output of the command would be the same as the format of your file.